# ConnectionPool.release Exception in node js

Tags: sql-server, node.js, sql-server-2012

I have used node js to connect mssql database server

We are facing connection pool release exception.

Find the code snippet and issue in below

**Code:**

```
var sql = require('mssql')
var dbconfig = {
    server: 'xxxx',
    database: 'xxxx',
    user: 'xxx',
    password: 'xxx',
    port: 'xx'
};
try {
    sql.close();
    var connection = sql.connect(dbconfig, function (err) {

        if (err) console.log(err);

        var sqlquery = '';
        var request = new sql.Request();
        //query to the database and get the repo value
        sqlquery = 'select Repo from verylargetable';
        request.query(sqlquery, function (err, result) {
            if (err) console.log(err)
            var repo = result.recordset[0].Repo;

            //query to the database and get the commit value
            sqlquery = "select Commit from verylargetable where Repo='" + repo + "'";
            request.query(sqlquery, function (err, result) {
                if (err) console.log(err)
                var comm = result.recordset[0].Commit;

                //query to the database and update the table
                sqlquery = "UPDATE verylargetable set Repo='" + repo + "', WHERE Comm='" + comm + "'";
                request.query(sqlquery, function (err, result) {
                    if (err) console.log(err)
                    console.log("record(s) updated");
                });
            });
        });
    });
}
catch (e) {
    console.log("===========Exception Occurred==========");
    console.log(e);
    console.log(new Date().toString());
    console.log("==========================================================");
}
```

**Issue:**

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'release' of null
>           at ConnectionPool.release (/usr/lib/Webhook/node_modules/mssql/lib/base.js:199:14)
>           at Request.userCallback (/usr/lib/Webhook/node_modules/mssql/lib/tedious.js:608:25)
>           at Request._this.callback (/usr/lib/Webhook/node_modules/tedious/lib/request.js:47:27)
>           at Connection.message (/usr/lib/Webhook/node_modules/tedious/lib/connection.js:1401:27)
>           at Connection.dispatchEvent (/usr/lib/Webhook/node_modules/tedious/lib/connection.js:687:45)
>           at MessageIO. (/usr/lib/Webhook/node_modules/tedious/lib/connection.js:602:18)
>           at emitNone (events.js:67:13)
>           at MessageIO.emit (events.js:166:7)
>           at ReadablePacketStream. (/usr/lib/EJ2Webhook/node_modules/tedious/lib/message-io.js:102:16)
>           at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
>           at ReadablePacketStream.emit (events.js:169:7)

How to resolve this exception and how to handle exception in query execution?

Answer (score 0):

Try follow:

```
        request = new sql.Request();
        sqlquery = "select Commit from verylargetable where Repo='" + repo + "'";
        request.query(sqlquery, function (err, result) {
```

So get new request before every action.